# Does Express.js support sending unbuffered progressively flushed responses?

Tags: node.js, express, catalyst

Perl's Catalyst framework permitts you to send an progressively flushed response over an open connection. You could for instance use [`write_fh()` on Catalyst::Response](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aResponse#res-write_fh). I've begun using Node.js, and I can't find how to do the equivalent.

If I want to send a big CSV file, on the order of 200 megs is there a way to do that without buffering the whole CSV file in memory? Granted, the client will timeout if you don't send data in a certain amount of time, so a promise would be nice if -- but is there anyway to do this?

When I try to do a `res.send(text)` in a callback, I get

```
Express
500 Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
```

And, it doesn't seem that Express.js supports an explicit `socket.close()` or anything of the ilk.

Here is an example,

```
exports.foo = function (res) {                          
  var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM naics.codes");
  query.on('row', function(row) {                       
    //console.log(row);                                 
    res.write("GOT A ROW");                             
  });                                                   
  query.on('end', function() {                          
    res.end();                                          
    client.end();                                       
  });                                                   
};
```

I would expect for that to send "GOT A ROW" out for each row, until the call to `client.end()` signifying completion.

Comment: How are you using the export? What results are you getting from that export?

Comment: Export is in a model that is called by a route. It's like it doesn't get the copy of res that I send to foo(), I wonder if it is a threading error or something underneath.

Comment: Change `exports.foo` from `function(res)` to `function(req, res)`. You are passing in the request instead of the response.

Comment: @hexacyanide no difference, I was only sending it res from the route. this code comes from a db-interface that I keep my SQL in. I don't actually like even sending it `res`, but I do it out of necessity.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Express is built on the native HTTP module, which means `res` is an instance of [`http.ServerResponse`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse), which inherits from the [writable stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_stream) interface. That said, you can do this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var stream = fs.createReadStream('./file.csv');
  stream.pipe(res);

  // or use event handlers
  stream.on('data', function(data) {
    res.write(data);
  });

  stream.on('end', function() {
    res.end();
  });
});
```

The reason you can't use the `res.send()` method in Express for streams is because it will use `res.close()` automatically for you.

Comment: I updated with an example. I'll try your code just for fun but your idea didn't work for me.