# Node/Hapi.js - How to stream/append result set from database via hapi.js?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, tedious

I'm trying to create REST service that returns data from database as a response via hapi.js.

I'm using tedious to execute SQL queries and I want to format results as JSON or XML and return them as a response of hapi request. Note that this is not tedious-specific, I can have the same problem with any database.
Tedious has a callback that is invoked each time it receives a new row from the result set:

```
sqlRequest.on('row', function (columns) {
        fnOutput(columns[0].value);
});
```

This is the simplest example with one column output. fnOutput is a custom function that accepts text that should be returned. It can concatenate results and format them as JSON that will be returned to client.

I'm getting row-by-row and I want to concatenate values in rows and return them to the client via hapi. 
How to continuously send partial results to the response?

1. I don't want to concatenate all rows in this callback and then push entire formatted JSON when the query is finished. I don't know how many records I will have and I want to avoid big strings that will be accumulated.
2. If I try to call reply(columns[0].value) in fnOutput each time I get new row, it fails when second row is returned with:
   "reply interface called twice"

Is there some way to continuously append results in this callback to hapi.js output stream each time I get new row in callback function?

Comment: What version of hapi?

Comment: Latest version ^12.1.0

Comment: Does the database driver you are using support streaming results?

Comment: tedious is event based so it run callback every time it receives a new row. I have found some requests to support streaming but it seems that it is not implemented.

Comment: I believe that I'm looking for something like response.write method from express http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857693/does-express-js-support-sending-unbuffered-progressively-flushed-responses . Is there an equivalent or anything similar in hapijs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to write the data to the raw response using `request.raw.res.write()`

`request.raw.res` is the raw ServerResponse object, and you can find the documentation for the `write` method here: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback

Once you are done writing data, you'll need to tell hapi that you are done handling the request manually by calling `reply.close()`

Something similar to this (untested):

```
sqlRequest.on('row', function (columns) {
    request.raw.res.write(columns[0].value);
});

sqlRequest.on('done', function () {
    reply.continue();
});
```

Comment: You are right, this solved the problem. Instead of reply.continue() I have used request.raw.res.end() because I have passed entire reply.raw.res object to my function. If works great.