# How to send stream of json object to the client?

Tags: json, angular, express, stream, response

*This can be a duplicate question but cant find any solution out there. I already tried to search it on this fast hours but I am out of luck.*

My question is how I can send *stream*(idk if stream is the right term) of json objects to the client.

Example I am reading data on the DB, and on every 5 records it found I will send the data to the client in json format. Then read the data on the client using Angular httpclient lib.

I already tried expressjs `response.write()`, but the client was unable to receive the data until I call `response.end()`.

What is the proper way of doing this?

I was thinking about socket.io but that would be overkill.

**Edit**

Other exmple

```
function getData(res: Response, req: Request):void {
  for(let i = 0; i<100; i++{
    res.write(JSON.stringify({data:1}) + '\n');
  }

  res.end(); // There is data received on the browser until this was called.
}
```

Or something like this. I was expecting a data will reach every 1 second but they came up at the same time after 10s.

```
function getData(res, req){
  const s = setInterval(()=>{
    res.write(JSON.stringify({value: 'test value'}));
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(()=>{
    clearInterval(s);
    res.end();
  }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857693/does-express-js-support-sending-unbuffered-progressively-flushed-responses

Comment: @AnandUndavia the solution there, I think that still boils down to ```res.end()```

Answer (score 0):

So I found this out that the sample code above is doesn't have problem and also the right way to do it.

When I tried to open the url API directly to the browser, I can see that the browser is receiving the data.

The problem is on the angular httpclient lib that I use to fetch the data, it will show the data if everything is already downloaded.

But luckily I found this package [oboe.js](https://github.com/jimhigson/oboe.js) , it can do what I want to stream the json data. So when the express js will send data via `res.write()` oboe will able to retrieve the data and ready for consumption.

You can do it as simple as this.

```
oboe('your url').node('!', data=>{
  // process your data here.
  // the '!' selector means that oboe will just show the data if it is a valid json.
});
```