# Is there oboe.js alternative for angular 7?

Tags: angular, oboe.js

I have other question here [How to send stream of json object to the client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53719665/how-to-send-stream-of-json-object-to-the-client), but luckily I found a solution using oboe.js.

I wonder if there is a any features on angular like oboe have?

I tried `HttpRequest` then enabling the `reportProgress` but it will just show what the status of the stream without the data.

Comment: What is your question exactly ? If you are looking for a solution built in the Angular framework, then no, if you are asking if oboeJs works with Angular then I see no reason why not.

Comment: @CornelC thanks, I was looking for a solution built in the Angular framework. Apparently as you said, the answer is no.